# echo status value from WC_Order Object of Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**How can I echo the status from the WC_Order Object from WooCommerce from a Wordpress Plugin?**

I seem to be able to echo every other value except that one. Here is the object:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

WC_Order Object
(
    [id] => 222
    [prices_include_tax] => 
    [tax_display_cart] => excl
    [display_totals_ex_tax] => 1
    [display_cart_ex_tax] => 1
    [order_date] => 2014-12-17 01:30:06
    [modified_date] => 2014-12-17 01:30:08
    [customer_message] => 
    [customer_note] => 
    [post_status] => publish
    [status] => processing
)
```

I have been able to echo the id using:

```
echo $order->id;
```

When I try this, it's blank:

```
echo $order->status;
```

Comment: What is your WooCommerce version?

Comment: I'm using version 2.1.6

Answer (score 2):

Correct way to get status is via get_status method:

```
$order->get_status();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by putting the the Object into an array. My guess is that the status was a private object member.